# save and handle files in Docker application

Tags: docker, ftp, filesystems

Our application run in a Docker Container. The application retrieves files from a directory outside our network. The application needs to process the files and save them somewhere for a year.

What is the best approach? Do we use the writable part of the Docker or a directory on the hosting system? what is the addvantages and drawbacks?

Answer (score 2):

Preferably you have your container as dumb as possible. Also if your container gets killed or crashes, you would lose your data if you have it stored within the container.
A volume mount would be a possible solution, what would make it possible to store files directly to the host; but my question would then be: why using Docker?
Another advantage of having a quite dumb container is that you would be able to scale more easily. Having a queue, you could scale the amount of containers needed upto the a certain threshold to process the queue. :-)

Therefore I would advise you to store the data somewhere else; another FTP-server, hosted and managed by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. If I use another FTP-server. Is it better to use Volume mount or Bind mount?

Comment: Another question. If I use antoher FTP server and Volumes. Do I need to install Docker on the new FTP Server?

Comment: It does not really matter which you use, however Docker tells you that a Bind is more explicit: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#choosing-the--v-or---mount-flag  There is no per say need to install Docker on the new FTP server, since the container can create a connection towards the FTP server.